# Autocomplete Not Showing Results That Are Returned

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I cannot get the results of a jQuery UI autocomplete to show, although the php code returns json results. The jquery code is as follows:

```
$("#newName").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: root + "/assets/php/autocomplete.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                term : request.term,
                field : "name"
            },
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

The php code is:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['value'] = $row[$field];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

When checking the results in Firebug, I get a response such as:

```
[{"value":"jdoe"}]
```

However, I never see a list of suggestions showing in the html page.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I fixed the problem by adding to my master css file a z-index style for the autocomplete. Everything now works properly.

```
.ui-autocomplete {
z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: This fixed it for me but my z-index was much, much higher because I was doing this in a modal "popup." So, make sure you test your z-index: `console.log("z-index: " + $(".selector").zIndex());`

Comment: In some cases its also z-index:9999999999; ;-)

Answer (score 15):

I have the same problem.
For me solution is to set z-index to higher value like this

```
.ui-autocomplete
{
    position:absolute;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:1001 !important
}
```

Some elements hide autocomplete form.
(in my app)

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP code try to change 'value' for 'label':

```
while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['label'] = $row[$field];
    array_push($return_arr,$row_array);
}

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

I don't know why, but it seems that this is important. I will attached the example that worked for me. In my case I had to do a MySQL connection from jQuery through a PHP file. I wanted to do an autocomplete field where you could write a username and, when you clicked on the username, the related fields (name, surname, email...) were populated. Here is my code:

**HTML code:**

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"   
      </script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <!--Here there is my jQuery script-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/myjQuery.js"></script>

      <title>EXAMPLE AUTOCOMPLETE</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <h1>CREATING A NEW CASE</h1>         
     <form id='newcase' action="#" method="POST" name="newcase">      

      <label>Add Nickname </label>
      <input class="input-250" type="text" id="nickname" name="nickname"><br/>

      <label>First Name </label>
      <input class="input-250" type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"><br/>

      <label>Surname </label>
      <input class="input-250" type="text" id="surn" name="surn"><br/>

      <label>Organisation</label>
      <input  class="input-250"type="text" id="organisation" name="organisation"><br/>

      <label>E-Mail Address </label>
      <input class="input-250" type="text" id="email" name="email"><br/>

    </form>
   </body>
 </html>
```

**myjQuery.js:**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

      $('#nickname').autocomplete({

       //Here I call the PHP file and the method inside this file, separated by '/'.
       //You should manage it somehow to make this possible.
     //I have managed it whith a PHP file called index.php, that gets whatever it comes 
    //from the URL after the 'rt' and it separates it by the slash,
   //being the first value the name of the file, and the second value the name of the 
   //method.

     source:'index.php?rt=jscallsController/listNicknameUsers', 
     minLength:1,
     select: function(evt, ui)
     {
      // when a username is selected, populate related fields in this form

        document.getElementById('firstname').value = ui.item.firstname;
        document.getElementById('surn').value  = ui.item.surname;
        document.getElementById('organisation').value  = ui.item.org;
        document.getElementById('email').value  = ui.item.mail;
        }
      });
    });
```

**And the PHP file jscallsController.php:**

```
    <?php

    class jscallsController{

    public function listNicknameUsers(){

      $hostdb = 'localhost';
      $namedb = 'tests';
      $userdb = 'username';
      $passdb = 'password';

      $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

      $users  = 'table_users';

      $data = array();

     try {
      // Connect and create the PDO object
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);

      // Sets encoding UTF-8
      $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      

      //Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
      $sql = "SELECT u_name, u_fname, u_surname, u_organisation, u_email FROM $users  
              WHERE u_name LIKE '$term%'";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);

      // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
      if($result !== false) {

      // Number of returned rows
      $rows = $result->rowCount();   

      //If exists, returns 1
      if($rows > 0){
          foreach($result as $user) {

          /*The first position of the array needs to be called 'label', 
          otherwise it will not show anything in the HTML field 
          where the autocomplete is done.*/

          $data[] = array(

          'label' => $user['u_name']." (".$user['u_fname']." ".$user['u_surname'].")" ,
          'firstname' =>$user['u_fname'],
           'surname' => $user['u_surname'],
           'org' => $user['u_organisation'],
           'mail' => $user['u_email']
         );
        }
      }
     }
     //Disconnect
     $conn = null;        

     //We send back the array to the jQuery
     echo json_encode($data);
     }
     catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo $e->getMessage();
      }
     }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: i liked your implementation

Comment: /*The first position of the array needs to be called 'label', 
          otherwise it will not show anything in the HTML field 
          where the autocomplete is done.*/ has been the savior.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it worked for me

```
.ui-front {
    z-index: 1500 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answers that are proposing using CSS are actually just working round the problem. According to the [JQuery Automcomplete API docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo), you should add the class `ui-front` to the element you want the autocomplete list appended to (which will most likely be the parent of the `#newName` element), otherwise it just gets chucked into the body of the page.

Alternatively, you can specify the id of the parent as the `appendTo` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem with a **secondary autocomplete text from a modal.**

A second unordered list with `ui-id-2` which contains the returned data has it's `display` property set to `none`. So I had to update that as well with the z-index.

```
#ui-id-2.ui-autocomplete.ui-front 
{
  z-index: 99999 !important;
  display: block !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share what solved my problem.

it's very common but might help others.

besides from including `jquery-ui.js` on your project. **ALWAYS MAKE SURE THAT YOU ALSO INCLUDE** `jquery-ui.css`

```
<link href="Stylesheets/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try this?

```
data: {
    term : request.value,
    field : "name"
},
```

Your array key is `'value'`, not `'term'`

Comment: Just tried that change but it made no difference. I still a response back in the form of [{"value":"jdoe"}] when looking throug Firebug but the results do not show in the html page.

Comment: try to remove this field : "name".
your input Id is newName ?

Comment: It appears to be a CSS style problem. If I remove all CSS style sheets, I get the following message beside the textbox:

1 result is available, use up and down arrow keys

Comment: Just discovered that the results are showing in a dropdown, but it is hidden behind the form. I have to move the form to see it. Must be a styling issue, if I can only discover where.

Comment: in your jquery ui.css ? use firebug to inspect the form